# android - ArrayAdapter notifyDataSetChanged() called from Handler.post randomly does not call GetView

Tags: android, multithreading, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have searched between many notifyDataSetChanged() issue questions without finding my specific case, so here it is:

### Problem

I have a root thread (started by the UI thread) that listen for something.
Everytime it receives a message, it starts a new thread (let's call them children threads) that does some operations and, at the end of its life, **notifies to the UI adapter** that an object has been added.

This procedure works 99.99% of the time (I have stressed a lot the program) but in some cases that I cannot understand this notification does not work.

I am sure that the problem is the listview because the two above statements (setImageBitmap) work properly, changing the imageViews images.

### Code

**Handler initialization in the Activity and passed to the class that works with threads**

```
//class scope variable
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler(new IncomingHandlerCallback(this));

//At the end of the activity class
/**
 * ref. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/1aPZXZG6kWk/lIYDavGYn5UJ 
 */
class IncomingHandlerCallback implements Handler.Callback {

    Activity activity;      
    
    public IncomingHandlerCallback(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        
        DeviceUtils.hideKeyboard(activity);
        
        switch (msg.what) {
        case EXECUTE_CODE_UPDATE_TCP_COUNT:
            updateDebugCounter(true);
            break;
        .
        .
        .
        case EXECUTE_CODE_UPDATE_LIST_COUNT:
            updateDebugCounter(false);
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Like the comment says that declaration is taken [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-developers/1aPZXZG6kWk/lIYDavGYn5UJ)

**Custom Array Adapter**

```
public class PlateInfoListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlateInfo> {

    private final Activity context;
    CheckBox selectAll;
    List<PlateInfo> plateList;  
    AnprInterface anprInterface;
    private MobileANPRDetailPopup readingDetailPopup;

    public PlateInfoListAdapter(Activity context, List<PlateInfo> plateList, CheckBox selectAll, AnprInterface anprInterface) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_plate_list, 0,
                plateList);
        this.context = context;
        this.selectAll = selectAll;
        this.plateList = plateList;
        this.anprInterface = anprInterface;
        
        final LayoutInflater factory = context.getLayoutInflater();
        readingDetailPopup = new MobileANPRDetailPopup(context, factory.inflate(R.layout.popup_mobile_anpr_reading_detail, null));
        readingDetailPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(Reso.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.grey_border_white_bck));
        readingDetailPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        readingDetailPopup.update();
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected LinearLayout layout;
        protected CheckBox checkBox;
        protected TextView date;
        protected TextView plate;
        protected TextView plateCountry;
        protected ImageView blackList;
        protected ImageView whiteList;
        protected ImageButton readingDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        PlateInfo plateInfo = plateList.get(position);
        boolean hotlistDrawn = false;
        
        if(plateList.size() == 1) {
            selectAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.adapter_plate_list, null);
            
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_plate_layout);
            viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_plate);
            viewHolder.plate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_plate_plate);
            viewHolder.plateCountry = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_plate_country);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_plate_data);
            viewHolder.blackList = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_plate_blacklist);
            viewHolder.whiteList = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_plate_whitelist);
            
            viewHolder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 
                    
                 // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    plateList.get(getPosition).setRowChecked(buttonView.isChecked());
                }
            });
            
            viewHolder.readingDetail = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.ib_plate_detail);
            viewHolder.readingDetail.setFocusable(false);
            viewHolder.readingDetail.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            viewHolder.readingDetail.setTag(plateInfo);
            viewHolder.readingDetail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(anprInterface.isReading()) {
                        return;
                    }
                    
                    PlateInfo selectedPlateInfo = (PlateInfo) viewHolder.readingDetail.getTag();
                    
                    if(selectedPlateInfo != null) {
                        readingDetailPopup.showCentered(v, selectedPlateInfo);
                    }
                }
            });
            
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        // Restore the checked state properly
        holder.checkBox.setTag(position);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(plateInfo.isRowChecked());
        holder.plate.setText(plateInfo.getPlate());
        holder.plateCountry.setText(plateInfo.getPlateCountry());
        holder.date.setText(DateUtils.formatHelianDateToCustomHumanDate("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy", plateInfo.getDate()));
        holder.readingDetail.setTag(plateInfo);
        
        if(plateInfo.getBlackWhiteListNote() != null && !plateInfo.getBlackWhiteListNote().equals("")) {
            if(plateInfo.getBlackWhiteListNote().contains("WHITELIST")) {
                holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Reso.getColor(context, R.color.red_light));
                holder.whiteList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                
                hotlistDrawn = true;
            }
            else {
                holder.whiteList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
                
            if(plateInfo.getBlackWhiteListNote().contains("BLACKLIST")) {
                holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Reso.getColor(context, R.color.red_light));
                holder.blackList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                
                hotlistDrawn = true;
            }
            else {
                holder.blackList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        else {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Reso.getColor(context, R.color.transparent));
            holder.whiteList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.blackList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        
        if(plateInfo.isRowSelected()) {
            if(hotlistDrawn) {
                holder.layout.setBackgroundDrawable(Reso.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.list_selector_red_bck_blue_border_normal));
            }
            else {
                holder.layout.setBackgroundDrawable(Reso.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.list_selector_blue_border_normal));    
            }
        }
        else if(hotlistDrawn) {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Reso.getColor(context, R.color.red_light));
        }
        else {
            holder.layout.setBackgroundColor(Reso.getColor(context, R.color.transparent));
        }
        
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return plateList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlateInfo getItem(int position) {
        return plateList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**The following code is called by the children threads.**

**Here it is the code that generates the issue:**

```
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                                         
                    mLastPlateImage.setImageBitmap(plateImage);
                    mLastContextImage.setImageBitmap(contextImageResized);
                    
                    mPlateInfoList.add(0, plateInfo);
                    
                    // That is the problem
                    mPlateListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    
                    System.gc();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Just to be sure: your `mHandler` is initialized using `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`?

Comment: No, I am editing the question with its initialization, give me a second

Comment: Activities are created on the Main thread, so that Handler ends up using the correct Looper. Nevertheless, I prefer to be explicit about it, prevent surprises.

Comment: where are you sending message to your handler? there must be something like handler.sendMessage(EXECUTE_CODE_UPDATE_TCP_COUNT);

Comment: where do you actually modify the adapter? I see the notifyDataSetChanged, but where do you actually update it's contents?

Comment: @santalu that message are not usefull for this question, I put them just for letting you know how I handle its message. For this specific case I use the post message of the Handler that does not use the handleMessage method.

Comment: @JaySoyer I update the content by adding the object to the mPlateInfoList List<PlateInfo> that is the list binded to the adapter with new PlateInfoListAdapter(this, mPlateInfoList, mCbSelectAll, mAnprInterface);

Comment: can you post `PlateInfoListAdapter` !

Comment: Yes, please post adapter code...or are you just using a standard ArrayAdapter?

Comment: At the moment I don't have the code under my hands, since I am not at home. This evening, about at 21 00, I will be able to do that. Thank you guys for the support

Comment: @JaySoyer I have added the adapter code

Comment: @mmlooloo Any possibile solutions?

Comment: Are you sure `notifyDataSetChanged` is not firing `getView`...or that it's firing `getView` but not actually updating the screen correctly? As in, you've placed log statements in the `getView` method to know for sure it's not being called?

Comment: @JaySoyer Yes I am. Luckly the bug appeared when the device was linked with Eclipse, so I placed a breakpoint into getView method and while in debug I tried to reach getView method. But it didn't work at all.

Comment: By any chance, does this bug occur after you perform a filtered search on the adapter?

Comment: No, the NotifyDataSetChanged() only updates the ListView with the given data. Nothing is filtered

Comment: Like I said above I update it here mPlateInfoList.add(0, plateInfo);
I am trying now to comment mPlateInfoList.add(0, plateInfo); and mPlateListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); and update the adapter content by doing: mPlateListAdapter.insert(plateInfo, 0);

I have already tried it and works correctly like the original code.
Should this fix something?